# Get user country by using Wi-Fi

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-location

I am looking for a way to get the user's country by using the Wi-Fi.
So far I have managed to do it using `TelephonyManager` and the SIM card, like this

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String s = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

This works ok, but the problem is, the user may not have a sim card (a tablet), so I also need to be able to determine the country by using the Wi-Fi they are connected to.

I tried this code, but its not working as I want it to, I simply want a country code, like US, UK, DE, instead this method returns GPS coordinates...

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.v("LOCATION", location.getProvider());
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
      };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

How can I get the country using the Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You require to do reverse geocoding, i.e. converting location you get to address. For this you can use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses;
try {
      addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1); //1 - is number of result you want you write it any integer value. But as you require country name 1 will suffice.
      if (addresses.size() > 0) 
             System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
} catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with GeoCoder, heres a snippet of code for checking WiFi and obtaining location info:

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {

        // any location
        // Getting network status

        Log.e("GPS Service", "Get Location Called");
        isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.e("GPS Service", String.valueOf(isNetworkEnabled));

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            Log.e("GPS Service", "Yay Wifi Enabled");
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocation = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    Log.e("GPS Service", "Yay Location");
                    mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                    // location is available
                    return mLocation;
                }
            }
        }
        // If reaching here means, we were not able to get location neither
        // from GPS not Network,
        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            // so asking user to open GPS
            //askUserToOpenGPS();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // if reaching here means, location was not available, so setting the
    // flag as false
    isLocationAvailable = false;
    return null;
}


public String getCountryCode() {

    getLocation();

    if (isLocationAvailable) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            mLatitude = getLatitude();
            mLongitude = getLongitude();
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("returning", "tm");
            //TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            //return tm.getNetworkCountryIso();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            // Error message to post in the log
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments "
                    + Double.toString(mLatitude) + " , "
                    + Double.toString(mLongitude)
                    + " passed to address service";
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // Get the first address
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            /*
             * Format the first line of address (if available), city, and
             * country name.
             */
            // Return the text
            Log.e("returning", address.getCountryCode());

            String countrycode;

            if (address.getCountryCode() == null) {
                countrycode = "null";
            } else {
                countrycode = address.getCountryCode();
            }
            return countrycode;
        } else {
            return "null";
        }
    } else {
        //String locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
        Log.e("returning", "wifi");
        getJSON();
        Log.e("ELSE", wifiCode);
        return wifiCode;
    }
}
```